# Asp.net System.NullReferenceException when creating new MysqlConnection

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, nullreferenceexception

`I'm new to asp.net and when I tried to connect to  MySQL database I got this error.
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDw3N.png)

here is my code in web.config file

```
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    
      <add key="HostPrefix" value="/root" />
      <add key="ServerIp" value="localhost" />
      <add key="MysqlConnectionstring" value="server=localhost;Database=world;port=3306;user=root;password=1234;SslMode=none" />
      <add key="UserImagePath" value="world\city\" />
      
  </appSettings>
```

here is my code for database connection

```
using Common;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Configuration;

namespace Repositories
{
    public class StudentRepository
       
    {
         private string ConnectionstringMaster = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MysqlConnectionString"];

  private static readonly NLog.Logger Logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();        
       
public studentsModel UserRegistration(string Id )
        { studentsModel stud1 = new studentsModel();     

try
             {
string Query = "select ID,Name,CountryCode,District from world.city where ID='" + Id + "'";
using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionstringMaster))
                 
                 {
                      using (var command= new MySqlCommand(Query,connection))
                      {
                          connection.Open();
                          using (var sdr=command.ExecuteReader())
                          {
                              while (sdr.Read())
                              {
                                  
                                  stud1.FirstName = sdr["Name"].ToString();

                              }

                          }
                      }
                  }
                  return stud1;
                
                
            }
            catch (Exception e)
             {
                Logger.Info("inside Exception Repo Userregistration  "+e.ToString());
              
                return stud1;
             } 
            

           
        }
    }
}
```

Here I'm trying to get data from database and  assign those values to studentmodel stud1 . But when I try to create new MySQL connection  with my database in localhost
it gives exception like this .

**ispasswordExpired :connection.ispasswordExpired threw an exception of type 'System.nullReferenceException'**

**ServerThread :connection.ServerThread  threw an exception of type 'System.nullReferenceException'**

**ServerVersion : connection.ServerVersion  threw an exception of type 'System.nullReferenceException'**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to add the [connectionStrings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-strings-and-configuration-files) section in your `web.config` file and remove it from the `appSettings` section like this:

```
<configuration>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MysqlConnectionstring" connectionString="server=localhost;Database=world;port=3306;user=root;password=1234;SslMode=none" />
  </connectionStrings>
  
  <appSettings>  
      <add key="HostPrefix" value="/root" />
      <add key="ServerIp" value="localhost" />
      <add key="" value="" />
      <add key="UserImagePath" value="world\city\" />   
  </appSettings>
 
</configuration>
```

And then you can access the connection string value by accessing the `ConnectionString` property in your code like this:

```
private string ConnectionstringMaster = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MysqlConnectionstring"].ConnectionString;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `connectionStrings` to your Web.Config.

**Web.config**:

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MysqlConnectionstring" connectionString="Server=myServerName;Port=3306;Database=myDatabaseName;Uid=testUser;Pwd=myPassword;" />      
  </connectionStrings>
                     ...
</configuration>
```